# Issue when converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

everyone. I develop my project using Fabric.js and I have found an issue when converting to JSON

I crop an object. For cropping I use the function:

```
 activeObject.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="#A2322E";
    ctx.moveTo(-leftPointCropShape, -topPointCropShape+storonaX);
    ctx.lineTo(leftPointCropShape,-topPointCropShape);
    ctx.lineTo(leftPointCropShape,topPointCropShape);
    ctx.lineTo(-leftPointCropShape,topPointCropShape);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
};`
```

After  `JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());` I have the next string :

```
> {"objects":[{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":254,"top":44,"width":88,"height":144,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,
"clipTo":"function(ctx)
{\r\n\t\tctx.beginPath();\r\n\t//ctx.fillStyle=\"#A2322E\";
\r\n\tctx.moveTo(-leftPointCropShape,-topPointCropShape+storonaX);
\r\n\tctx.lineTo(leftPointCropShape,-topPointCropShape);
\r\n\tctx.lineTo(leftPointCropShape,topPointCropShape);
\r\n\tctx.lineTo(-leftPointCropShape,topPointCropShape);
\r\n\tctx.closePath();\r\n\t//ctx.fill();\r\n\t}",
"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"multiply","src":"http://localhost/test20/image/elements/shtora/3.png","filters":[],"crossOrigin":"","alignX":"none","alignY":"none","meetOrSlice":"meet"}],"background":"#F5F5F5"}
>
```

The problem is that there are variables' names in JSON instead of their values.

```
ctx.lineTo(leftPointCropShape,-topPointCropShape);
```

Is it Fabric's bug?

How can I insert values  instead of variables' names "leftPointCropShape","topPointCropShape"  in JSON ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to stringify a function. You can't do that. More to the point, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, you *can*, but it's not very useful.

Comment: Well, it *could* be useful for code generation.

Comment: And TIL what the `JSON.stringify` replacer parameter does. :)

Comment: Jokes aside, what you can do is create your own string by concating it. something like: *'\r\n\tctx.moveTo(+'-leftPointCropShape'+,'-topPointCropShape+storonaX');'*

Comment: @Andy, First, let me tell why would I want to do that.
I'm developing a project, where user can model curtains. Some elements should be skewed, using transform Matrix.
Skewed object dynamically is cropped.
So, the function clipTo() belongs to Fabric.js Object. The function that determines clipping of an object (context is passed as a first argument).

Comment: Now, let me say why I "stringify function".
I want to save canvas' state, in other words, to save user's project .
I use
JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
to get the JSON string.
As you can see in my answer above, the string contains object "parameters":"values",
but if an object was cropped, this function appears.

Comment: So, is it Fabric serializer's bug?